# The ending of adjective ganz

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

It seems that in the expression *in ganz Europa* one uses **ganz** without an ending. Why not *in ganzem/ganzen Europa*?

Comment: ich denke, dass es um eine Gradpartikel geht, lesen Sie hier: http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adverb/Partikel/Gradpartikel.html?MenuId=Word540… und könnten Sie bitte den ganzen Satz schreiben, indem man besser den Kontext verstehen kann?!

Comment: Arguably, *ganz* only remotely remains an adjective in the construction you cite because of the way it doesn’t inflect.

Comment: Neither _in ganzem_ nor _in ganzen_, but _im ganzen Europa_ could be possible. It’s hardly idiomatic, though.

Comment: @Jan Since you seem to be German and feel that this is not an adjective in this context, I tend to beleave you.

Comment: @IgorTraskunov *Not an adjective* is too strong. But *ganz* is definitely half way to becoming an uninflected indefinite article like *viel* or others. The first sentence could have changed in a few decades or centuries.

Answer (score 4):

You use this form when you don't use an article with the noun, so mostly with names.

> In ganz Köln gibt es kein besseres Bier.
>
> Ganz Europa feiert heute.

Just like you would not use an article with names ("Das Europa ist ein Kontinent" sounds odd).

Comment: Mostly place names, though. If you had some sentence where you wanted to say "in the whole of Robert" you'd say `im ganzen Robert`. It's a rare phrase normally, but might come up in book/author names though: "Im ganzen Dürrenmatt gibt es keine solche Figur"

Comment: @KWeiss Well, ok, especially when you think of the name of the work, like in "Im ganzen Werther". But there you don't use "ganz", you *do* add an ending.